# Will I get moderated if I call a statement 'idiotic'?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

There exists a highly upvoted answer from a high rep user which in addition to the technical aspect of the answer, inserts some (rather political) claim that I could not describe as anything but idiotic, even though I've tried hard to find a different adjective.

Will I get moderated if I call the statement 'idiotic'?

Comment: Is it idiotic though?

Comment: I couldn't describe it any other way

Comment: Is it idiotic to call something idiodic?

Comment: Only if it is idiotic to ask whether it is idiotic to call something idiotic.

Comment: Can link the example? Sound like this needs some more context. It's probably fine as long as you're not calling another user idiotic.

Comment: *"I couldn't describe it any other way"* Well, there is always "inane", "asinine", or "moronic", but they all suffer from the same fault as the original which is casting aspersion on the author of the statement you are responding to. In other words they'll start a fight. *Don't do that.* Stick to objective statements about the truth and back them up with authoritative sources.

Comment: Yes, idiotic isn't a polite term. Even idiots deserve politeness.

Comment: I think it would be inappropriate to link to the question. So I'm sure that it's hard to answer the question without more details. I guess I am just asking about what the general tolerance is for these kind of things.

Comment: I'd use a [different word](http://thesaurus.com/browse/stupid) if I were you.

Comment: Can you describe it as "too chatty","non-constructive","tangent"?  Just some more additions to @Sam's thesaurus :)

Comment: [lol, we have a lot of people calling themselves idiots.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=idiotic+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: Alright. I'll take @InfiniteRecursion's advice and try to use an alternative. The issue is not chattiness or the like. It is a bold claim about the alleged uselessness in a programming language of a pretty fundamental data-structure in computer science.

Comment: Hmm I guess it's arrays. Data-structures and design-patterns are two topics you shouldn't be emotional about. Every person has their own preferences and criticisms for these two things in programming.

Comment: This question is idiotic and anyone who condemns the word "idiotic" is idiotic.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Optimal algorithms for given problems don't always give room for choice of data-structures, but claiming that something like a Linked List is "useless" in any imperative, general purpose programming language, is especially annoying, especially coming from a high rep user who most viewers tend to trust.

Comment: Linked lists!! Please add a few polite words on my behalf too :)

Comment: If it doesn't strictly have to be an adjective, you could also say something like "I completely disagree with your point of view that arrays are useless." It's perfectly clear, without sounding like you're offending the other person.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> even though I've tried hard to find a different adjective.

Have you though? Here are a few suggestions:

- inflammatory
- polarizing
- wrong
- [not even wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong)
- misleading
- misguided
- unnecessary

These all have one thing in common: they're focused on the *statement you're addressing*, not the person who wrote it. "Idiotic" *can* be interpreted as a commentary on the statement as well, but in practice *will* often be interpreted as a personal attack.

If that's not what you're going for - and given you asked this question, I suspect you're hoping to avoid it - then you should strive to find a different term.

As for whether or not you'll be "moderated" for using the term "idiotic", that depends entirely on context. Again, if you have to ask...

Comment: Hah - you outraced me.  I'd cut misguided.  Unlike all the others, I can't imigine having it directed at my post without reading it as implying that *I* am misguided.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that; again, it depends on the context (which we don't have here) - there are a great many rules / "best practices" which get trotted out in situations where they're inapplicable (also a good term...) - that doesn't make them *bad*, but misguided (or merely unnecessary).

Comment: [Context](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267804/will-i-get-moderated-if-i-call-a-statement-idiotic?noredirect=1#comment72843_267804)

Comment: "Misleading" then, @Infinite.

Answer (score 3):

I have no authority here, but I feel like this is common sense:

You should strive to be civil in your interactions with other users wherever possible. If you get engaged in an off-topic flame war with another user, you should not be surprised if a mod gets involved. There is always a way to react to even the most uncivilized or off-topic of remarks in a way that does not use harsh language.

Do not forget that any time you call a post "idiotic" there is an implication that you are making a statement not just about the post but also the poster, even if you don't intend for it to be taken that way. Personal remarks are certainly not considered proper behavior for this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you probably will.**

We expect users here to correct errors, clarify others' posts, and even challenge ideas that are unsupported or appear incorrect.

**"Be nice."**

But we also expect users to treat each other respectfully and professionally, much as you would in real life, face-to-face, while talking to someone you want to respect you.

And certain terms are near-automatic failure there, because they are so insulting or so consistently interpreted to be about the *person*, even when you suggest they're about the post:

If you call a post idiotic, moronic, asinine, lazy, illiterate, etc. almost *any* poster will read them as attacks on them, not critiques of the post (they always feel ad hominim).

**You want them to learn something, yes?  Say it another way.**